# Geography Select Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, geography, sqlgeography

I have a SQL Server 2012 location table, which has a column `geo` of type `geography`

I have a user table which links to the location table

**location**

```
locationId int
geo geography
```

**user**

```
userId int
locationId int
```

I will know the id of the location and I know how to do a distance query with stdistance. But whats the best way of comparing the two distances in a query. I can do it with a subselect but is there a better way

The sub select looks something like

```
select 
   suburb, state, postcode, 
   geo.STDistance((select geo from location where locationId = 47))/1000 kms
from location
order by kms desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is location #47 special somehow? Will it always be 47? Either way, you can stick it in a variable

```
declare @HQ geography;
select @HQ = geo from location where locationid = 47;

select 
   suburb, state, postcode, 
   geo.STDistance(@HQ)/1000 kms
from location
order by kms desc
```

If you (for whatever reason) want it all in one query, you could try an outer apply

```
select 
   suburb, state, postcode, 
   geo.STDistance(HQ.geo)/1000 kms
from location
outer apply (select geo from location where locationid = 47) as HQ
order by kms desc
```

Comment: `select @HQ geo from location where locationid = 47;` should be `select @HQ = geo from location where locationid = 47;` NOTE: missing = sign

Comment: Right you are. Fixed!